# XCode iOS - Need help on Compiling C Error

Tags: iphone, c, xcode, compiler-errors

I'm trying include this barcode source code [Stefanhafeneger - Barcode github.com](https://github.com/stefanhafeneger/Barcode) to my project because this is the only DataMatrix library for iOS I can find so far. I have no problem compile and run the source code on xcode 4.2 but when i try to use the library in my project. I received quite lots of error as follows.

[image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2305062/Screen%20Shot%202012-04-07%20at%2003.13.08.png]

After some surfing, i found that they were foundation error which i think is cause by the .C files for example file - dmtx.c it is under libdmtx library.

When i remove the library for debugging all error were gone and left 'dmtx.h' file not found so i think xcode does regconized these files. Any idea to compile these C files?

Many Thanks
Kin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake, the problem was cause by my prefix file.

Comment: I had the same problem with MyApp-Prefix.pch file. The solution was to move all the objectiveC import statatement into the guard #ifdef __OBJC__

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that you did not have the Foundation.framework instanciated in your project...

Comment: The foundation.framework is included as default, i pretty sure it was included because my project could compile properly after i remove the Libdmtx library.